# Empty for loop - for(;;)

Tags: javascript

I was exploring the [Google Closure Compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home), and one thing I noticed was that it converts `while(true)` into `for(;;)`.

Both do hang the browser, but why does the empty `for` loop not break out of itself immediately? The second part of it is empty, and therefore falsy. Isn't it true that when the second part is falsy, the `for` loop stops and execution continues with code which comes after the `for` loop?

Could someone perhaps give an explanation for this?

Comment: Maybe it's faster... someone should benchmark them :)

Comment: Well, it's smaller - that's what the compiler does: just minifying your code (it is a great tool really)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

No, it is not true.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for

> condition
>
> An expression to be evaluated before each loop iteration. If this
>   expression evaluates to true,
>   statement is executed. This
>   conditional test is optional. **If
>   omitted, the condition always
>   evaluates to true**. If the expression
>   evaluates to false, execution skips to
>   the first expression following the for
>   construct.

I should perhaps give a link to ECMAScript reference, but I'm pretty sure it states more or less same thing.

Comment: Good luck. I just went through the [ECMA-262 specs](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf) for `for` loops and they are generally inscrutable. The above behavior is a consequence of following the steps in the spec, rather than being explicitly mandated by it.

Comment: Oh well... Then I suppose Mozilla's reference and my word that all popular variants of ECMAScript behave this way must be enough. :D

Answer (score 4):

From the [ECMAScript language specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf):

IterationStatement : for (ExpressionNoIn_opt ; Expression_opt ; Expression_opt) Statement

If the first Expression is present, then

1. Let testExprRef be the result of evaluating the first Expression.
2. If GetValue(testExprRef) is false, return (normal, V, empty).

Since the first expression (the second argument to for) is not present, this section is never run, so the for loop does not exit.

Answer (score 2):

An empty middle part should be interpreted as `true`, so it's not falsy. It has the same semantics in C and other languages with that kind of loop (like C#, Java and so on). It would be a real trap to have changed it for JavaScript.

Comment: I didn't know that. Also I'm not wanting it to have it changed, I was just wondering.

Comment: @pimvdb: I understood that as well :) I just wanted to point out that it wasn't really up to the creator of JavaScript. He just had to do what everyone else was doing (or confuse a lot of people). On second thought, I guess he did confuse people anyway, but with other parts of the language :D

Answer (score 1):

There is evaluation algorothm of for loop in Standard ECMA-262 script that says there are only two situations in which loop will end:

1. break statement
2. value of middle statement equal to *false*, **but only if this statement is present**, so it doesnt have to be necessary valuated as *true* (probably in mozilla js engine it is).