# Javascript for (;;)

Tags: javascript

I came across something in the uBlock origin [source](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/blob/master/src/js/reverselookup.js) and couldn't find any explanation or documentation on it.

```
for (;;) {
    pos = content.indexOf(compiledFilter, pos);
    if ( pos === -1 ) { break; }
    // We need an exact match.
    // https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/issues/1392
    // https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/issues/835
    const notFound = pos !== 0 &&
                     content.charCodeAt(pos - 1) !== 0x0A;
    pos += compiledFilter.length;
    if (
        notFound ||
        pos !== content.length && content.charCodeAt(pos) !== 0x0A
    ) {
        continue;
    }
}
```

What exactly does `for (;;)` do and what benefits does it offer?

Comment: It's an infinite loop, just like `while (true)`

Comment: [Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bjs%5d%20code%3a%22for(%3b%3b)%22) of [In JavaScript what does for(;;){...} do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4904880/4642212).

Answer (score 3):

The syntax of `for` loop is like

```
for(initialization; condition; increment/decrement){
}
```

Now if you want to skip any of those three steps you can just leave its space empty but put the semicolon. In the above example, the user is skipping all three steps.

As mentioned, it will be an infinite loop. If you don't `break` or `return` inside the loop, the JavaScript code (and in the browser, the entire tab) will hang with high CPU usage.

**Note:** I won't recommend using something like this. This is kind of unfamiliar way. `while(true){ ... }` achieves the same behavior, but is easier to read.

Comment: “increment/decrement” is often summarized as “update”. _“the system will hang”_ — No, the process, or the thread, not the system.

Comment: ...that's because is a discouraged pattern.

Comment: @MarioVernari I agree this way shouldn't be used.

Comment: The warning at the end is unnecessary IMO. `for (;;)` is a common idiom. It's not "tricky complex", just unfamiliar.