# Why is for(;;){…} an infinite loop?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Empty for loop - for(;;)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4740979/empty-for-loop-for)

I just found a strange construct in the JS parser of UglifyJS (at [L1045](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS/blob/master/lib/parse-js.js#L1045)): `for(;;){…}`.

I assumed that an empty condition would resolve to `undefined`, which is converted to the boolean value `false`. But that's definitely not the case.

Apparently, it triggers an infinite loop. I was able to reproduce this behavior, but I have no clue why. Any (logical) explanations?

Besides: When this is possible, why doesn't `while(){…}` work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's just the definition of the semantics.  A missing "test" expression is treated as an expression with the value `true`. Languages are made up by people, and they are at liberty to specify any behavior they like. Clearly, that behavior is something Mr. Eich likes :-)

Comment: Here’s the spec on that: http://es5.github.com/x12.html#x12.6.3

Comment: Oh thanks it was taking forever to load for me, for some reason :-)

Comment: Apparently it wasn't the only odd thing Mr. Eich liked;)

Comment: Yes but overall I appreciate his work!

Comment: Actually, that behavior is something Dennis Ritchie liked, since it's inherited from C ;) Although, maybe C got it from an earlier language like B or BCPL.

Comment: Hey that's a good point. I haven't written a C program in so long that I didn't even wonder about it. You're right though, now that you mention it. I don't think I ever found that to be strange behavior; I guess it's a matter of expectations.

Answer (score 4):

`for(;;){…}` interprets an empty condition as `true` and `while(){}` is not considered as valid. As said before it's totally language dependant but described in the specification.

Answer (score 1):

In the [ECMA-262 language specification of JavaScript](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) (section 12.6.3) it is defined how the behaviour of the for loop should be.

You can see from the definition that if the information around and between the semi-colons is not available, there are no conditions to leave the loop. The only way to leave the loop is by defining a test condition and optionally some start and step values.

The behaviour could be defined in a different way but that's just not how it is.

Answer (score 1):

From the [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf).

```
12.6.3 The for Statement
    The production
        IterationStatement : for (ExpressionNoIn(opt) ; Expression(opt) ; Expression(opt)) Statement
    is evaluated as follows:
    1. If ExpressionNoIn is present, then.
        a. Let exprRef be the result of evaluating ExpressionNoIn.
        b. Call GetValue(exprRef). (This value is not used but the call may have side-effects.)
    2. Let V = empty.
    3. Repeat
        a. If the first Expression is present, then
            i. Let testExprRef be the result of evaluating the first Expression.
            ii. If ToBoolean(GetValue(testExprRef)) is false, return (normal, V, empty) .
        b. Let stmt be the result of evaluating Statement.© Ecma International 2011 91
        c. If stmt.value is not empty, let V = stmt.value
        d. If stmt.type is break and stmt.target is in the current label set, return (normal, V, empty) .
        e. If stmt.type is not continue || stmt.target is not in the current label set, then
            i. If stmt is an abrupt completion, return stmt.
        f. If the second Expression is present, then
            i. Let incExprRef be the result of evaluating the second Expression.
            ii. Call GetValue(incExprRef). (This value is not used.
```

**Gist of this spec**: for statement stops when first Expression returns "falsey" value.

Since absence of expression doesn't return false, the script will run forever (or until `break` statement is executed from inside the loop body).