# Why use an empty for loop in Javascript--for(;;)?

Tags: javascript, performance, syntax

I forget where now, but I read somewhere that `for(;;){...}` is the same as saying `while(1){...}`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4740979/empty-for-loop-for) confirms that this is true and explains why `for(;;)` works at all. However, it doesn't elaborate on why it would be useful, and I can't seem to find any benchmarks for the empty `for` loop as opposed to the `while` loop.

It's rather confusing (although admittedly quite clever), but it *is* shorter. Google's Closure Compiler converts `while(true)` to empty for loops, so there must be a reason.

**tl;dr**: Why should I use an empty for loop over a `while(1)` loop?

Comment: It is a preference thing, one is not better than the other.

Comment: Personally I think it should fail, since the "condition" is empty and therefore falsy...

Comment: @Kolink: Indeed, so do I. But that's the way C and (I believe) Java do it, and to change that would just confuse a lot of people. :)

Comment: To make people pause _for_ a _while_ at your code.

Comment: @nhahtdh: You win the prize for Worst Pun of the Day, officially. :-)

Comment: @Kolink I agree, also `while(1)` and `for(;;)` don't really say anything to me semantically. `while(true)` says a lot more.

Comment: They are the same in performance: http://jsperf.com/for-vs-while-tests

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: Well, `while(1)` is different, because `1` evaluates to a truthy value whereas an empty statement does not.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville: Actually, an empty statement is true. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth ;)

Comment: @tskuzzy: Nice. But hey, if `truthy` and `falsy` work for Douglas Crockford, the demigod of JS, they work for me.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville I was talking more about the semantics of the statement and not what they evaluate to. What is `1` and what does that mean when someone looks at it. If I showed someone who had never seen an infinite loop in this form they would know immediately what `while(true)` means.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: I suppose it's really a matter of opinion. I see `1` and I automatically think `number` and then `truthy value`. There's not much of a difference. It depends on whether the person in question is an experienced programmer or not. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's shorter to type. That's really the only reason. A lot of people just grew up programming that way and it's a matter of habit.

I vaguely remember there being a time and language where `for(;;)` was faster. But that's by and large in the past now with any half-decent optimizing compiler/interpreter.

Comment: @Derek: Thanks for the test, guess there's not really any difference between the two.

Answer (score 3):

It's slightly more idiomatic, presumably because it's shorter to type and there was an era in which that mattered more than code readability.  I have read in software engineering books that `for(;;)` jumps out to mean "infinite loop" more readily than `while(1)`, so if it's a convention better to stick with it.  It's by no means a strong convention though and they are technically equivalent in any aspect I can think of.