# why does empty conditional statement for java for loop evaluate to true?

Tags: java, for-loop, conditional-statements

I apologize if this question has been asked somewhere in [Empty for loop - for(;;)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4740979/empty-for-loop-for) or else where on the site.

I was wondering if any one knows why java would choose for their parser/compiler to evaluate an empty conditional statement in a for(;;){} loop as true instead of perhaps null or void ?

as linked by user @Mchi

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for

"An expression to be evaluated before each loop iteration. If this expression evaluates to true, statement is executed. This conditional test is optional. If omitted, the condition always evaluates to true. If the expression evaluates to false, execution skips to the first expression following the for construct."

I am just curious.

Comment: The opposite should be false. Not null or void

Comment: Probably because Java inherited this feature from C++ which inherited it from C and someone long ago in the 1970's cam up with the idea that `for (;;)` should be an finite loop.

Comment: Please tag your questions correctly.  Java and Javascript are different languages.

Comment: (In Java ... a loop doesn't "evaluate" to anything.  It is not an expression.)

Comment: Are you referring to Java or JavaScript?

Comment: sorry, I fixed it (Java), didn't expect such fast replies - thanks

Comment: You originally tagged as "Java" but all your links are to resources about JavaScript. I'm voting to close as unclear, since it's hard to tell from the question body which language you're even intending to ask about.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not seem to benefit the SO community

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A conditional statement must be of `boolean` type in order to control looping, in exactly the same way that the expression within an `if()` or a `while()` statement must be of `boolean` type.

The only valid values for `boolean` are `true` and `false`.  So, `null` and `void` are not applicable, they do not make any sense.

As for empty conditional statements, of the two possible values `true` and `false`, they chose `true` because there is absolutely never any need for a loop that will not loop at all, while there are plenty of situations where we have a need for a loop that will loop forever (or until `break`.)

Comment: That, and for a looping construct, it makes sense to choose `true` as default.

Comment: @HuguesMoreau that's right, I amended my answer to indicate that.

Comment: Thanks, I guess not

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "I guess not".  This was not a "yes/no" type of question.

Comment: "because there is absolutely never any need for a loop that will not loop at all" sorry meant I agree with this quote - I guess there isn't

Comment: figuring out how to quote/tag users properly

Comment: It's okay, if you comment on my own answer then I am automatically notified without a need to tag me.